# Which is correct: "in twos" or "by twos"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am confused about the preposition in this sentence:

> The students left the classroom "*in* twos" or "*by* twos".

Which form is correct?

Comment: "In pairs" would be an improved form. If you wanted to use the phrase "by two" it is usually used as follows;  "The students left the classroom two by two."

Comment: 'Two by two' for Noah's Ark inferences.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Only for the "unclean" animals. The "clean" animals (and all types of bird) were to be taken in seven pairs [Genesis 7:2–3](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/Gen%207.2%E2%80%933).

Comment: @TripeHound Indeed, but most people recognise 'two by two' - possibly from [nursery rhymes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuQjR2lsYl0).

Comment: "... two at a time."

Answer (score 2):

"In twos" is correct. I'm not sure where you got "by twos" from.

Merriam webster:

> ***in twos***
>
> in groups of two